# Entity partially saved when using JOINED inheritance strategy and setting spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Java Spring Boot application using Spring Data, a MySql database,
and two small classes that I want to persist in database using JOINED inheritance strategy.

Here is some code:

The pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>oli</groupId>
    <artifactId>BugInheritanceBatch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BugInheritanceBatch</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The App class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

The BaseTable entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class BaseTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private long value;

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

The SubTable entity:

```
@Entity
public class SubTable extends BaseTable {
    private String name;    

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

The DAO:

```
public interface BaseTableDao extends CrudRepository<BaseTable, Long> {

    List<BaseTable> findAll();
}
```

Everything works fine using this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
public class BaseTableDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private BaseTableDao dao;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        SubTable item = new SubTable();
        item.setName("name");
        item.setValue(33);
        item = dao.save(item);

        // make sure our inserted item received an ID
        Long id = item.getId();
        Assert.assertNotNull(id);

        // make sure we have 1 item in the table
        List<BaseTable> items = dao.findAll();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, items.size());

        // make sure the item's type is correct and contains the expected values
        Assert.assertTrue(items.get(0) instanceof SubTable);
        SubTable insertedItem = (SubTable) items.get(0);
        Assert.assertEquals((long) id, (long) insertedItem.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals("name", insertedItem.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(33, insertedItem.getValue());
    }
}
```

However if I add this line in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
```

Then the test fails with a

```
JpaSystemException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: BaseTable...
```

After investigating a bit and checking the database itself, I saw that this exception is thrown by dao.findAll() statement because dao.save() partially saves the entity (only base_table is updated, sub_table is not). Besides, I get a strange log form Hibernate:

```
HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

But the INSERT statement logged by Hibernate is correct.

Do you have any idea to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. I just needed to use the latest version of Hibernate.

I updated my pom.xml as follows:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <hibernate.version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```